# Problem about incentre of a triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

> Through the incentre $I$ of triangle $ABC$ a straight line is drawn intersecting $AB$ and
>   $BC$ at points $M$ and $N$, respectively, in such a way that the triangle $BMN$ is acute-
>   angled. On the side $AC$ the points $K$ and $L$ are chosen such that $∠ILA = ∠IMB$
>   and $∠IKC = ∠INB$. Prove that $AC = AM + KL + CN$.

I have no idea how to start.

I can only see triangle IMC' and ILB' are congruent but not triangle IMC' and IKB'. I wonder if my diagram is different from yours.

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show us your attempts.

Comment: Do you know the AAS (Angle-Angle-Side) Theorem for triangle congruence?

Comment: Cleverly done @Michael.  Too bad I can't upvote your answer.  The OP has to cooperate if your answer is to appear in vote-able form!

Comment: @sailormars2016 Please change the title of the question according to your problem. It should be related with the question, not with its context or detailes.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, how does AAS help? I solved the problem using Ptolemy's theorem. Is there a very simple solution I am missing?

Comment: I'm using triangle congruences.  AAS comes in via that method.  Before posting I need to know whether the OP has seen it.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi, which triangles are congruent?

Comment: Draw perpendiculars from $I$ to $C'$ on $\overline{AB}$ and to $B'$ on $\overline{AC}$.  Also draw $\overline {IA}$.  Claimed:  Right triangles $IKB'$ and $IMC'$ are congruent by AAS, sides $\overline {IK}$ and $\overline {IM}$ are congruent, triangles $IAK$ and $IAM$ are congruent by AAS, sides $\overline {AK}$ and $\overline {AM}$ are congruent.  Similarly $\overline{CL}$ and $\overline{CN}$ are congruent.

Comment: I can only see triangle IMC' and ILB' are congruent but not triangle IMC' and IKB'.  I wonder if my diagram is different from yours.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$, $Q$ and $R$ be touching points of the incircle to $BC$, $AC$ and $AB$ respectively.

Also, let $M\in AR$, $N\in PC$, $MR=x$ and $PN=y$.

Thus, since $\Delta MRI\cong\Delta LQI$ and $\Delta NPI\cong\Delta KQI,$ in the standard notation we obtain: 
$$AM+KL+CN=\frac{b+c-a}{2}-x+x+y+\frac{a+b-c}{2}-y=b=AC$$ and we are done!